# Fill forward duplicates from date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently working on SQL Server and I have a table which registers schedule changes from the date registered forward (NULL is employee day off)

The problem is when I try unpivot the table and join with calendar table it duplicates the values if there has been 2 or more changes it duplicates the values starting from the date of change.

Here is what I've been doing so far

```
`IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ScheduleChange') Is Not Null Drop Table #ScheduleChange
Create table #ScheduleChange(ChangeDate Date, EmployeeId NVARCHAR(50), Monday NVARCHAR(50), Tuesday NVARCHAR(50), Wednesday NVARCHAR(50), Thursday NVARCHAR(50), Friday NVARCHAR(50), Saturday NVARCHAR(50), Sunday NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #ScheduleChange VALUES
('2024-01-02','100', '11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m.', '11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m.','11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m.','11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m.','11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m.',NULL,'10:00 a.m.-2:00 p.m.'),
('2024-01-14','100','9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m','9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m','9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m','9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m','9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m',NULL,'10:00 a.m.-2:00 p.m.'),
('2024-01-04', '200','9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m.','9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m.','9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m.','9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m.','9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m.','9:00 a.m.-1:00 p.m.',NULL),
('2024-01-10','200','10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m.','10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m.','10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m.','10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m.','10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m.','10:00 a.m.-2:00 p.m.',NULL)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar') Is Not Null Drop Table #Calendar
Create table #Calendar(Date Date, WeekDayName NVARCHAR(15))
Declare @Start Date
Set @Start = '20240101'

WHILE @Start <= Cast(Getdate()-1 As Date)
BEGIN
  INSERT #Calendar
  Select @Start,
  DATENAME(DW,@Start)

 Set @Start =Dateadd(day,1,@Start)
End

;WITH
schedules
AS
(
    SELECT ChangeDate, EmployeeId, Schedule, WeekDayName
    FROM #ScheduleChange
    unpivot
    (
      Schedule
      for WeekDayName in (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday)
    ) unpiv
)
    SELECT schedules.*, #Calendar.Date
    FROM schedules JOIN #Calendar ON #Calendar.date >= schedules.ChangeDate AND schedules.WeekDayName = #Calendar.WeekDayName
    ORDER BY schedules.EmployeeId, schedules.ChangeDate`
```

The result gives me duplicates from that date forward.

Is there any way to overwrite the schedule once there's a change from that date forward instead of duplicating everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using the `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...)` pattern to select the *latest* applicable schedule for each employee and calendar date combination.

This would require some restructuring of the query to extract distinct employee information, cross apply that to the calendar, and then for any given employee/date combination, select the appropriate schedule row.

```
WITH schedules AS (
    SELECT ChangeDate, EmployeeId, Schedule, WeekDayName
    FROM #ScheduleChange
    unpivot
    (
      Schedule
      for WeekDayName in (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday)
    ) unpiv
),
employees AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId
    FROM #ScheduleChange
)
SELECT E.EmployeeId, C.Date, S.WeekdayName, S.Schedule, S.ChangeDate
FROM employees E
CROSS JOIN #Calendar C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM schedules S
    WHERE S.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
    AND S.ChangeDate <= C.date
    AND S.WeekDayName = C.WeekDayName
    ORDER BY S.ChangeDate DESC
) S
ORDER BY
    S.EmployeeId, 
    C.Date,
    S.ChangeDate
```

Results:

| EmployeeId | Date | WeekdayName | Schedule | ChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2024-01-02 | Tuesday | 11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m. | 2024-01-02 |
| 100 | 2024-01-03 | Wednesday | 11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m. | 2024-01-02 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | 2024-01-11 | Thursday | 11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m. | 2024-01-02 |
| 100 | 2024-01-12 | Friday | 11:00 a.m.-7:00 p.m. | 2024-01-02 |
| 100 | 2024-01-14 | Sunday | 10:00 a.m.-2:00 p.m. | 2024-01-14 |
| 100 | 2024-01-15 | Monday | 9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m | 2024-01-14 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | 2024-01-29 | Monday | 9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m | 2024-01-14 |
| 100 | 2024-01-30 | Tuesday | 9:00 a.m-5:00 p.m | 2024-01-14 |
| 200 | 2024-01-04 | Thursday | 9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m. | 2024-01-04 |
| 200 | 2024-01-05 | Friday | 9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m. | 2024-01-04 |
| 200 | 2024-01-06 | Saturday | 9:00 a.m.-1:00 p.m. | 2024-01-04 |
| 200 | 2024-01-08 | Monday | 9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m. | 2024-01-04 |
| 200 | 2024-01-09 | Tuesday | 9:00 a.m.-5:00 p.m. | 2024-01-04 |
| 200 | 2024-01-10 | Wednesday | 10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m. | 2024-01-10 |
| 200 | 2024-01-11 | Thursday | 10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m. | 2024-01-10 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 200 | 2024-01-29 | Monday | 10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m. | 2024-01-10 |
| 200 | 2024-01-30 | Tuesday | 10:00 a.m.-6:00 p.m. | 2024-01-10 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qt4DF9F0).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. I just has to store the unpivot table in a temp table because with a couple more of values the query was getting a bit slow.